# How to use result of formula calculation from previous row(like in excel) in R

Tags: r

E.G. we have a data frame

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=4:8)
```

i need to calculate sum of a + b for row multiplying on result of this calculations for previous row. In excel this should be like a C2 = (A2 + B2) * C1
Please help

Comment: What is the starting value `C1`?

Comment: The c1 value should be 0

Comment: `df$c <- 0;for(i in seq_len(nrow(df))[-1]) df$c[i] <- (df$a[i] + df$b[i])*df$c[i - 1]`.

Comment: Thank you, are there way to do this in mutate?

Comment: If C1 is 0, all subsequent rows will contain 0.

Comment: @MrGumble, Yes my fault, if row is first then c1 = a1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 interpretations, either a cummulative accumulation where

```
C3 = (A2+B2)*C2 = (A2+B2)*(A1+A1)* ...
```

or a simple lagged product:

```
C1 = (A1+B1)
C2 = (A2+B2)*(A1+B1)
C3 = (A3+B3)*(A2+B1)
```

For 1), you can simply use the cumulative product:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=4:8)
df$C <- with(df, a+b)
df$C <- with(df, cumprod(C))
df
  a b     C
1 1 4     5
2 2 5    35
3 3 6   315
4 4 7  3465
5 5 8 45045
```

For 2) you multiple the result with an offset vector of the result:

```
df <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=4:8)
df$C <- with(df, a+b)
df$C <- with(df, C*c(1,C[-length(C)]))
df
  a b   C
1 1 4   5
2 2 5  35
3 3 6  63
4 4 7  99
5 5 8 143
```

Comment: Great, the second example is the key!